# Android Multi-threading: What Can & Should Be Run in Parallel?

Tags: android, multithreading, parallel-processing

Doing some performance optimizations and considering running some tasks in parallel.

Specifically thinking some DB & network operations as they should not bottleneck each other.

The only thing I'm worried is if this will cause problems on lower end devices, still lots of single core phones around. The app has minSDK=10.

For each question please consider it in context of device compatibility:

- Can independent Db & Network calls be ran in parallel without problems ?
- Does it make sense to consider parallel read-only DB calls ?
- Does it make sense to run Network tasks in parallel ?
- Any conventions around how many threads should run in parallel ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

DB calls:
- usually databases do not give away 100% of the resources to one call, so yes, multiple calls might help, especially if one request takes the longer time to process in database, but the data are small, anything longer than 100ms,

- in the case where the amount of data is big and processing the request in DB is short, then access in multiple calls and limited network speed could lead into issues, like timing etc,
- you have to take into consideration if on given device the bottleneck would not be network speed or the customer with limited network etc.

network calls:

- I would suggest that the criteria would be very same as with DB calls, lets say it can not be a shocker as DB calls are network calls:).

parallel read only calls to db:

- yes, I know cases where it can be fruitful, but I would say for most cases on small devices, it would be too much hassle that could work only in few specific situations, so in general, I would not recommend that,

number of threads, that is device and app
specific question based on:

- saving power is priority,
- data throughput or latency is priority,
- fast computed results from data is priority,
- etc.